# What is sum of integer values of $m$ so that $\frac1x+\frac1{x+1}=\frac1m$ has answer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> What is sum of integer values of $m$ so that $\frac1x+\frac1{x+1}=\frac1m$ has answer?
> $1)\text{zero}\qquad\qquad2)1\qquad\qquad3)7\qquad\qquad4)-10$

This is a high school level problem so I think by answer it means $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Here is my answer:

We have $m\neq0$ and $x\neq0,-1$

$$\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x}=\frac1m\;\Rightarrow\; x^2+x=2mx+m\;\;\Rightarrow\;x^2+(1-2m)x-m=0$$
We have$\;\Delta=(1-2m)^2+4m=4m^2+1$. Which is always positive. Hence there are always two values for  $x$ satisfies the original equation regardless of value of $m$  (if I plug in $x=0,-1$ in above equation I get $m=0$ which is a contradiction). And answer is "zero".

Is my solution right?

Comment: So if you have solution for any integer $m$ (not zero), then the sum of all integers is not defined.

Comment: If $x$ is allowed to be real, then all $m$ are valid, as you have shown.  But perhaps $x$ is meant to be an integer.

Comment: $0$ seems most likely of those on offer, though possibly because there is no integer solution for $x$ when $m$ is a non-zero integer.

Comment: That's a problem of very poor quality, not stating whether $x$ has to be integer and much more than that, implying that the set of solutions is $\{0\}$ when the integer equation has none, or possibly meaning that "the sum of the empry set is `zero'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer must be $0$ (if there are at most finitely many such $m$) by symmetry.  If $(x, x+1)$ yields a solution $m$, then $(-(x+1), -x)$ also yields the solution $-m$.